# How can I convert this SQL query to MS Access query?

Tags: sql, ms-access, distinct

I have Query in SQL

```
SELECT        COUNT(DISTINCT dbo.Polling_Stations.P_ID) AS [Male Stations]
FROM            dbo.Agent INNER JOIN
                     dbo.Polling_Stations ON dbo.Agent.P_ID = dbo.Polling_Stations.P_ID
GROUP BY dbo.Polling_Stations.Gender
HAVING        (dbo.Polling_Stations.Gender = N'Male')
```

I have converted it to Access as:

```
SELECT        COUNT(DISTINCT Polling_Stations.P_ID) AS [Male Stations]
FROM            Agent INNER JOIN
                     Polling_Stations ON Agent.P_ID = Polling_Stations.P_ID
GROUP BY Polling_Stations.Gender
HAVING        (Polling_Stations.Gender = 'Male')
```

But it giving me an error :
Syntax error(missing Operator) in query expression 'Count(DISTINCT Polling_Stations.P_ID)'.

Comment: What's your sentax error?

Comment: Syntax error(missing Operator) in query expression 'Count(DISTINCT Polling_Stations.P_ID)'.

Comment: Are square brackets valid in access?

Comment: Not related to your problem, but the filter on gender should be in a where clause, not a having clause.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Access SQL does not support `COUNT(DISTINCT ...)`, so instead you'll need to do

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS [Male Stations]
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT Polling_Stations.P_ID
    FROM Agent INNER JOIN Polling_Stations 
        ON Agent.P_ID = Polling_Stations.P_ID
    WHERE Polling_Stations.Gender = "Male"
)
```

Answer (score 4):

Access doesn't support `Count(DISTINCT ...)`.  `SELECT DISTINCT` in a subquery, and do the counting from the parent query.

```sql
SELECT COUNT(ps.P_ID) AS [Male Stations]
FROM
    Agent
    INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT P_ID
        FROM Polling_Stations
        WHERE Gender = 'Male'
    ) AS ps
    ON Agent.P_ID = ps.P_ID;
```